# How to get AMD Radeon HD 5450 drivers on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, radeon, amd-graphics

I am using Ubuntu 16.04. I bought a AMD Radeon HD 5450 graphics card, and I need the drivers. The box came with a disk for the drivers, but it is only compatible with Windows. Where can I get the driver for a Radeon HD 5450 graphics card in Ubuntu 16.04?

Comment: You card works with the open-source *radeon* driver and that is already the default. No user action needed.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on your exact graphics hardware, Ubuntu 16.04 will use either the open-source AMDGPU driver or the open-source Radeon driver, both of which are included in the default Ubuntu installation. The amdgpu driver, pre-installed in 16.04, is used for AMD's newest graphics cards. The radeon driver, also pre-installed in 16.04, is used for older AMD graphics cards that the amdgpu driver doesn't support (your graphics card was launched in 2010).