# Radeon 5450 OpenGL compatibiliy

Tags: 16.04, radeon, cad

My question is related to this one: [How to get AMD Radeon HD 5450 drivers on Ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/840261/how-to-get-amd-radeon-hd-5450-drivers-on-ubuntu-16-04/840286#840286)

My setup is working, though really not optimally; the display is SO slow with CAD software!

I am using Radeon HD5450 on Ubuntu 16.04 with the 'out of the box' driver, and I can't manage to improve it.

I think it has to do with the radeon driver, but I don't know how to adjust it.

One way could be to disable it and fold back on the onboard gfx card when working on CAD software (yes, it is that bad!)...

Comment: Hello and welcome to AU.  As such, your text is not an answer to the question you refer but it is not a question neither, at least, not explicitly.  Could you more clearly explain what you want to ask?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. And thank you for your attention. The problem is following : with ubuntu16.04.3, I had the radeon driver working (almost fine) for a HD5450 card. But my favorite cad sw is not wortking : that is the sole exception. OpenGL or any component is not working. I was looking how to improve the setup to get the cad sw working too.

Comment: Could you please [edit] your post when you want to clarify something or add information? It’s best to have everything relevant in one place. Additionally, comments may be deleted for various reasons. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ubuntu 14.04.5/16.04 and newer on AMD graphics](https://askubuntu.com/questions/815591/ubuntu-14-04-5-16-04-and-newer-on-amd-graphics)

Answer (score 1):

I have had to re upgrade, because I couldn't go back.

With the base components from 18.04, the radeon card is working again, and so is the CAD software.

So I can't explain why or how, but it seems the radeon open source driver is better in 18.04 than it was in 16.04.3.